# How to know if firefox is using master password, from command line or some programming language?

Tags: firefox

How to know if firefox is using master password, from command line or some programming language? Only if firefox is using, not what is it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go in the current profile folder and check the files which would be protected by the master password. If you can open them and read something that is not gibberish, there is no protection. If it is gibberish then there is a master password.

The files `key3.db` and `logins.json` store your passwords (cf https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)

This will work even if firefox is not running which seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: How I know if something is not gibberish?

Comment: Well the files are using plaintext if they're not protected. I guess you could for example check if there is a lot of control characters for example that shouldn't appear in a plain text file. You can use your own file as an example of what you should expect